# Is it possible to use React DnD to drop element on another browser tab?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

It is possible using the HTML API for the drag and drop.

But I want to use React DnD since it provides a lot of awesome features and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So As the title said; is it possible the use React DnD to drop elements on another browser tab ?

A code sandbox Example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-dnd-from-to-another-browser-window-example-28lrx?file=/src/BoxWithImage.jsx).
If you open this example on two browser window. Then try to drag and drop from one to another. you will be able to drop only the first element (the DnD image) however you can't drop the second element. Is there a way to get it to work ?

Answer (score -3):

Using React DnD it is not possible , but you can use WASM with rust to implement for cross browser it is possible, you can refer this repo to implement it , but it won't be easy https://github.com/Xavientois/dragula-rs